# Null value of variable in select statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a combined multiple insert query into a single query(say `combine1.sql`)

```
--insert query 1
--insert query 2
.
.
.
Declare @Tbl_Id INT
Select @Tbl_Id = Id from students where Code='123'
--null value comes in @Tbl_Id
insert into mappingtable values(@Tbl_Id, getdate())

.
.
.
--insert query n
```

I get null value in `@Tbl_Id` when I execute `combine1.sql`,
however, when I execute just

```
    Declare @Tbl_Id INT
    Select @Tbl_Id = Id from students where Code='123'
    --5 comes in @Tbl_Id
    insert into mappingtable values(@Tbl_Id, getdate())
```

What possibly is going wrong in `combine1.sql`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: show code block for insert query 1

Comment: Impossible to tell without more code. I suspect that you've currently misdiagnosed the issue, but when the only code you're showing us is identical between the two blocks, we're unlikely to spot the fault. Try to create a [mcve] you can share with us.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to check value of @Tbl_Id like this

```
 Declare @Tbl_Id INT
    Select @Tbl_Id = Id from students where Code='123'
    --5 comes in @Tbl_Id
    if(@Tbl_Id is not null)
    begin
          insert into mappingtable values(@Tbl_Id, getdate())
    end
```

Comment: my question is why I'm getting null value for the first time not how should i avoid inserting null values

Comment: where Code='123' this condition may be first time false so it is assign null value to @Tbl_Id

Comment: I'm lot looping hence there is no case of it being false for the first time